# AngularJS - refreshing list with new data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following partial:

```
<table ng-controller="WebsitesController">
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="website in websites.data">
        <td>{{website.name}}</td>
        <td>{{website.url}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('WebsitesController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: config.serverUrl + '/websites'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.websites = response.data.message;
    });
});
```

I successfuly load data into my view with this.

But Let's say I want to add "Delete" for each of the items. After the delete  process - how is it possible to refresh the list without refreshing the page?

I'm assuming that putting the GET call in a "re-usable" function is included in the process, right?

Comment: do you mean you want to remove a row or rows from your object array

Comment: I want to "re-load" the websites on my view without refreshing

Comment: It's done by angular called two-way-data-binding as far you delete a whole 'website' object and the length of the websites.data will be changed. if you change a single property, you maybe fire a digest cycle by your own.

Comment: By 'delete process', do you mean deleting the object from the db?

Comment: you are using variable "websites.data" in your template.When you will change that variable from JS (controller) it will update the UI without refresh. Angular keeps in sync the data model and rendered UI if everything is binded properly.

Comment: Just grab the list data from the db again, or remove the specific item from the array.  You do't need to do anything else

Comment: Yes, deleting from DB. this is already working, I successfully delete the item and then I use GET to get the updated list, but how do I update my view with the new data while doing it the angular way?

Comment: Remove it manually after you do the deletion in the db (maybe in the successCallback of your delete http request). Angular will automatically update your array in the view (only if you delete a whole 'website' object in your websites.data). If you change a single property of your 'website' object, you maybe have to call a $scope.$apply afterwards, but I don't think thats your point of interest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the object from the array, example:

```
<table ng-controller="WebsitesController">
     <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="website in websites.data">
           <td>{{website.name}}</td>
           <td>{{website.url}}</td>
           <td><button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

And the remove implantation:

```
$scope.remove = function( index ) {
     var removedElement = $scope.websites.data.splice(index, 1);
     console.log( removedElement );
};
```

Basically, you're removing the element from the array by passing its index (the index is invoked by the `ngRepeat` loop) the the remove function.

Edit: Please read the @charlietfl's comments when applying filters on the `ngRepeat` loop

Comment: I think you might need to remove it from $scope.websites.data but this answer is right. The magic of data binding means that when you remove the item from the array, the view is updated automagically.

Comment: But be careful using `$index` passed to controller...any filters on `ng-repeat` will change correct index. Safer to do indexing yourself

Comment: This is indeed the answer. I didn't know i can "update" $scope.websites. its really useful, thank you!

Comment: @charlietfl - Good point. Is there a "simple" workaround when using filters, or should I create a function that get the element itself and search for its index in the array?

Comment: Just pass object in .... then do `var index = $scope.websites.data.indexOf(passedInObject)` and make sure it isn't `-1`

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for this tip

Comment: Alon beat me to the answer but I was going to say you could use something like this:  $scope.websites.data.indexOf(this) but I'm not 100% sure on that

Comment: @tutley You can, and you should when applying filters on the `ngRepeat` loop - As mentioned in @charlietfl's comment - I haven't edited my answer since there aren't any filters in this case)

Comment: Guys after adding a required filter, this doesn't work for me anymore. `$scope.websites.data.splice( $scope.websites.data.indexOf(index) , 1);` `<tr ng-repeat="website in websites | orderBy: '-id' | limitTo: 10">`

Comment: @user3800799 - See @charlietfl comment, you need to pass to object itself to the function `ng-click="remove(website)"` and get the index using `var index = $scope.websites.data.indexOf(website)`